# A tag for the Christian relationship to the OT

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a number of questions about how Christians should relate to the OT. It might be how to interpret/use the laws, it might be about the usefulness of the OT in general, it might be about typology, or prophecy or many different things.

Some examples:

- [How is ignoring clear Biblical instructions in Leviticus justified?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30/how-is-ignoring-clear-biblical-instructions-in-leviticus-justified)
- [To what extent does the Law of Moses still apply?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply)
- [How does the Snake in the Desert foreshadow the coming of Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7026/how-does-the-snake-in-the-desert-foreshadow-the-coming-of-jesus)
- [Biblical Prophecy and Fulfillment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7209/biblical-prophecy-and-fulfillment)

I feel like it would be useful to have a general tag for how Christians use the OT, but I'm not sure what it should be called.

One option is something related to the discipline of Biblical Theology, which focuses on the progressive revelation of the Bible, but it's a much more specific topic than may be appropriate for some of these questions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure this is adequate, but it might cover a lot of them... "mosaic-law"

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with just `old-testament`? That is already a Christian word. It means nothing to Jews and Muslims call the whole Bible various other things.

Comment: It's like the difference between [tag:bible] and [tag:biblical-basis]. We have a tag for the [tag:old-testament], and I'm wondering if it would be useful to have one for the OT applied. Make any sense?

Comment: @curiousdannii I think I understand, but I have no idea of a word or phrase that would suffice. I'm also not sure that is necessary. I would argue for the demise of the `bible` tag. It's not very useful in the first place; much too broad. You could put it on nearly every question. It's almost as bad as having a `christian` or `christianity` tag.

Comment: I've been pruning the bible tag! Hopefully it will soon be mostly about canon questions. And yeah, we probably don't need a tag for this topic.

Answer (score -3):

perhaps "`dispensationalism`".

Comment: hey! what happened to my fish badges?  i used to have 6.  now i have 3.  what gives, mods?

Comment: Badges on meta site are awarded separately. [What you have on meta](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/users/9269/robert-bristow-johnson?tab=badges) and [what you have on main](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/9269/robert-bristow-johnson?tab=badges) are different because of your different activity on each.

Comment: Dispensationalism only applies to one theory of the relation.

Comment: you're absolutely correct dannii and thanks, fred, for the information on badges.